# Firebase storage rules "unauthorized"

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

These are my storage rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /auction-images/{auctionId} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.resource.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024
                   && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*');

    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I would like to allow all reads from `auction-images/{auctionId}`. When i tried running the simulator, it worked as expected.

However, when I start my application and try to load an image, it prints this error:

```
code: "storage/unauthorized"
code_: "storage/unauthorized"
message: "Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'auction-images/NVOi2jGlfDA5huPUzjSA'."
message_: "Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'auction-images/NVOi2jGlfDA5huPUzjSA'."
name: "FirebaseError"
name_: "FirebaseError"
serverResponse: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 403,↵    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"↵  }↵}"
serverResponse_: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 403,↵    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"↵  }↵}"
```

Even though I published the changes to my rules, they don't seem to take effect. What am I missing?

Here is the code that gives me an error:

```
this.firestorage.storage.ref(`auction-images/${this.recentAuctions[0].uuid}`).list().then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my rules were wrong. I updated them to this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /auction-images/{auctionId}/{image} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.resource.size < 1 * 1024 * 1024
                   && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*');
    }
  }
}
```

I thought that `match /auction-images/{auctionId}` would make it possible to write rules for the whole folder, but I had to to add `/{image}` for the rules to apply to the images inside.

Comment: That's correct. If `auctionId` is a folder, the rule is for the folder itself, not the items. By adding the wildcard at the end the rule is for the files inside. Btw, you can add a suffix like `.png` at the end to have the rule target a file type